# Is it possible to avoid LoadPostBackData event from ASP.Net Page life cycle

Tags: asp.net, postback

Is it possible to avoid the execution of `LoadPostBackData` event while PostBack happens. If it possible, how to implement that.

Thanks

Comment: no it is not possible. What is your issue?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to fail :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own control and not implement the [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.loadpostdata.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For a single page or control?  You can always override the method, then not call the base method implementation, but that will have repercussions.

Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do that?